# How to implement multiple Leaflet JS maps

Tags: javascript, php, leaflet

I'm having a lot of trouble defining multiple maps for all the maps on my website. With the code I have only two maps work, the rest don't appear. I have been searching for a problem similar to mine but I haven't come across any.

At the moment I create the div for the map getting the ID from my database in a loop;

```
<div id="map_<?php echo $data['property']->property_id;?>">...
```

Which outputs;

```
<div id="map_1"></div>
<div id="map_2"></div>
<div id="map_3"></div>
<div id="map_4"></div>
...
```

Those divs are on separate pages. Then I define the maps in my .js file which is where I think I am going wrong, at the moment I have the code below. Is this the wrong way to do it?

```
  const mapInfo = [{
      // Aldea Beach House
      id: 'map_1',
      coords: [36.33, -5.24],
      zoom: 11
    },
    // Princess Kristina
    {
      id: 'map_2',
      coords: [36.345, -5.24],
      zoom: 11
    },
    // Duquesa Marina Apartment
    {
      id: 'map_3',
      coords: [36.35, -5.23],
      zoom: 11
    },
    // Duquesa Golf
    {
      id: 'map_4',
      coords: [36.34, -5.24],
      zoom: 11
    },
    // Footer Map
    {
      id: 'map_footer',
      coords: [36.367, -5.23],
      zoom: 11
    }
    ];
    const maps = {};
    mapInfo.forEach(({
    id,
    coords,
    zoom
    }) => {
    maps[id] = L.map(id).setView(coords, zoom);

    L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw', {
      maxZoom: 18,
      attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
        'Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
      id: 'mapbox/streets-v11',
      tileSize: 512,
      zoomOffset: -1
  }).addTo(maps[id]);

  if (id === mapInfo[0].id) {
    L.marker([51.5, -0.09]).addTo(maps[id])
      .bindPopup("<b>Hello world!</b><br />I am a popup.").openPopup();
  }
})
```

UPDATE

- error

  ```
    Uncaught Error: Map container not found.
        _initContainer Map.js:1103
        initialize Map.js:136
        i Class.js:22
        map Map.js:1728
       <anonymous> main.js:45
       <anonymous> main.js:40
  ```

Comment: If you have the maps in the same page or script you can store the ids in an array and loop over them and don t have to replicate the same code

Comment: @kboul would you mind showing me what you mean in an answer that I can accept? I'm really new to this and it's confusing

Comment: @ jvern22 did the answer eventually work for you?

Comment: @kboul no sadly, I get an error I have added to my question in the console

Comment: Are you sure you adapted the answer correctly to your code? I don't have your actual script code so I cannot give more help. I think with the answer provided you can see the approach to follow. The rest is up to you to adapt it to your actual code.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure I did. if i try with just 1 map and name the id anything other than map it doesn't work @kboul

Comment: I edited my question to update the code i have now

Comment: I updated the code snippet with your exact same code again and there is no error. You have not included a div with a map id `map_footer`.  Did you include this div in your code ?`<div id="map_footer" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;"></div>
`? This is where the error comes from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the map ids or you can extract them somehow from your php code then you can create an associative array to keep track of the map instances and avoid copy pasting the same code by looping over them.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>

<title>Quick Start - Leaflet</title>

<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="docs/images/favicon.ico" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A==" crossorigin="" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA==" crossorigin=""></script>

<style>
.marginRight {
  margin-right: 10px
}
</style>

  </head>

  <body>


<div style="display:flex; flex-direction: row;">


<div id="map_1" class="marginRight" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;"></div>
<div id="map_2" class="marginRight" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;"></div>
<div id="map_3" class="marginRight" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;"></div>
<div id="map_4" class="marginRight" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;"></div>
<div id="map_footer" class="marginRight" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;"></div>
<script>
  const mapInfo = [{
      // Aldea Beach House
      id: 'map_1',
      coords: [36.33, -5.24],
      zoom: 11
    },
    // Princess Kristina
    {
      id: 'map_2',
      coords: [36.345, -5.24],
      zoom: 11
    },
    // Duquesa Marina Apartment
    {
      id: 'map_3',
      coords: [36.35, -5.23],
      zoom: 11
    },
    // Duquesa Golf
    {
      id: 'map_4',
      coords: [36.34, -5.24],
      zoom: 11
    },
    // Footer Map
    {
      id: 'map_footer',
      coords: [36.367, -5.23],
      zoom: 11
    }
  ];
  const maps = {};
  mapInfo.forEach(({
    id,
    coords,
    zoom
  }) => {
    maps[id] = L.map(id).setView(coords, zoom);

    L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw', {
      maxZoom: 18,
      attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
        'Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
      id: 'mapbox/streets-v11',
      tileSize: 512,
      zoomOffset: -1
    }).addTo(maps[id]);

    if (id === mapInfo[0].id) {
      L.marker([51.5, -0.09]).addTo(maps[id])
        .bindPopup("<b>Hello world!</b><br />I am a popup.").openPopup();
    }
  })

</script>



  </body>

</html>
```

You can even render things conditionally depending on the map id.

What you are doing is not wrong, you just reusing the same code chunk. I am not sure if that answers your question but you can follow this approach to avoid rewriting the same chunks of code

Comment: Ok, I understand what you mean but the coordinates are different for each map, how would I add that to the loop?

Comment: Where do they come from? I am not aware of that. You can adjust the code to include the desired coords in every map instance similar to the marker in the example or even better you can include them in the **ids array** to be **array of objects** that contains the ids, coordinates and any other data you wish to include. I will edit the answer to demonstrate it

Comment: Ok cool I think we have it as I just edited the question but I will try your answer now

Comment: I realized why it's not working for me, The `map_1` 2 etc arern't on the same page, it would only be one div. Is it possible to achieve that with the code you wrote somehow?

Comment: I am afraid I cannot help you more since I do not know how your pages look like and how you have structured them. I think I gave you a sufficient example to avoid copy pasting the same chunks of code. Now it is up to you to adapt it to your project.